# Asking for software recs which may need a combination of iOS & Windows software?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Is that going to be okay?

Before I post and people jump on me, which has become way too common SE sites, here's the sample outline:

Update: Since there were no replies I posted it and I hope people dont attack it with negatives. 
[Detect, identify & Extract Screenshots from iPhone using combination of iOS app & Windows program](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31132/combination-of-ios-app-windows-program-to-detect-identify-extract-screensho)

> I have taken a lot of screenshots on my iPhone over a long time for
>   lots of reasons.
>
> I need to be able to extract from iPhone to Windows 8.1 desktop, ALL
>   of them or SELECTED bunch of them.
>
> Given the structures & mechanisms of iOS 9.x it seems to keep/ mark or
>   filter all or most screenshots as if in a sub folder under Photos
>   called "Screenshots".
>
> From what I gather this is kind of a virtual folder on iOS
>
> I am wondering if there are iOS Apps & Windows Programs that I can use
>   in conjunction to extract these screenshots from the iPhone and
>   "permanently delete" them from the Phone as they are taking up space.
>
> I know for sure that I can't do this purely via software/ apps on one.
>   I'd be surprised if there is a way.
>
> Most likely I'll need:
>
> 1. iOS App:
>
>    - that can organize, tag, move or permanently create an isolated folder of screenshots or something that can be filtered/ recognized from the Windows side as a separate 'entity' {Given that even all Sub folders under Photos are technically only one large folder of Photos}
> 2. Windows Desktop Application/ Program:
>
>    - That allows me to selectively target this specific folder/ virtual folder tag.
> 3. Ideally, both of these are from a common vendor designed to work well together.
> 4. A scenario that popped up in my head
>
>    - An iOS App that allows us to export & clear out all these screenshots to a Flash/ Memory/ External disk - then it should be simpler to manage from Windows

Comment: "since there were no replies" – well, sometimes those take a little more than 5 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why this should not fit. It's clearly

- asking for software
- listing requirements
- giving a use-case so one gets an idea what it is about

It's only missing a few details (must it be free, or how much you're willing to pay? Any license restrictions, e.g. must it allow for commercial use?) – but that doesn't make it off-topic.